# menuitem inside box in shinydashboard mainpanel

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, menuitem

I would like to know if I could have something like `menuitem` inside my dashboard body in a shiny app ? in my example below, the `menuitem` works inside sidebar menu but not inside the box object !

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    menuItem("Dashboard",
             fileInput("upload", "Upload"),icon = icon("dashboard"))
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    box(width = 4, "test menuitem", solidHeader = TRUE,status = "success",
        menuItem("test",
                 fileInput("up", "Upload"),icon = icon("dashboard"))
        )
   
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: why not using a `tabBox`?

Comment: @Roman, `tabBox`  ?!!! I don't need a tab ! I need a foldable menu !

Comment: Your expected output isn't really clear to me but you might want to check [shinydashboardPlus::accordion()](https://shinydashboardplus.rinterface.com/articles/extra-elements.html#accordion)

Comment: @user9112767 sorry for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : `dropdownButton` from `shinyWidgets`

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h2("Dropdown Button"),
  br(),
  dropdownButton(

    tags$h3("List of Inputs"),

    selectInput(inputId = 'xcol',
                label = 'X Variable',
                choices = names(iris)),

    selectInput(inputId = 'ycol',
                label = 'Y Variable',
                choices = names(iris),
                selected = names(iris)[[2]]),

    sliderInput(inputId = 'clusters',
                label = 'Cluster count',
                value = 3,
                min = 1,
                max = 9),

    circle = TRUE, status = "danger",
    icon = icon("gear"), width = "300px",

    tooltip = tooltipOptions(title = "Click to see inputs !")
  ),

  plotOutput(outputId = 'plot1')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  selectedData <- reactive({
    iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
  })

  clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
              "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))

    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
    plot(selectedData(),
         col = clusters()$cluster,
         pch = 20, cex = 3)
    points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```